# libgdx FreeTypeFontGenerator: how to generate a string with TTF font file correctly?

Tags: android, fonts, libgdx

I use following code to generate font in libgdx:

```
class XFont {
    private FreeTypeFontGenerator _generator;    
    public BitmapFont getFont(String str,int size) {
                if (_generator == null) {
                    _generator = new FreeTypeFontGenerator(Gdx.files.internal("win/msyh.ttf"));
                    //_generator = new FreeTypeFontGenerator(Gdx.files.absolute("/system/fonts/DroidSansFallback.ttf"));
                    Gdx.app.log(TAG, "generator"+_generator.toString());
                }

                return _generator.generateFont(size, str, false);
            }
    }
```

when I call :

```
XFont x = new XFront();
x.getFont("iiiis",11);
```

raise exception:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Key with name 'i' is already in map.
```

I work with chinese and japanese.

Answer (score 1):

The `generateFont()` method takes a string containing the unique characters you'd like to be in the generated font. You then use that generated font to draw a string containing those characters - via `font.draw(batch, string, x, y)`.

Note: I'd recommend not generating a new BitmapFont every time you want to draw a String, but instead generate a font with all the characters you will likely use then reuse that BitmapFont.

Comment: my question is dummy.

Comment: the default chars is only some ascii chars. I have to erase duplicate chars in one string.

Comment: Right, the default chars is only some of the most common characters and symbols. You will need to determine a set of characters that encompasses those you will need. In any case, you should take every precaution not to generate a new font for each string you wish to draw.

Answer (score 0):

First, `_generator.generateFont(size, str, false)` take **str** as a string that contains all **unique characters** that you want to generate bitmap font. I preferred use charset for this. Then you should generate a bitmap font just **once**. Example:

```
// in your constants
public static final String FONT_CHARSET = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ 1234567890,./;'[]\\`~!@#$%^&*()_+{}|:\"<>?";    

// in your resource loading code
FreeTypeFontGenerator fontGenerator = new FreeTypeFontGenerator(Gdx.files.internal("myFont.ttf"));
BitmapFont myFont = fontGenerator.generateFont(24, FONT_CHARSET, false);
fontGenerator.dipose(); // remember to dispose the generator after used
```

The `FONT_CHARSET` contains all characters in the keyboard, I think it is enough for English texts.